# Only getting last single row in arraylist

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

I am trying to get the list of Array, using SELECT * from tableName. But I am just getting the last row only in strange way. I demonstrate us with example. I have just two rows of data, that I put manually. Let's say data are StackOverFlow and Google with Ids 1 and 2 respectfully. What I am getting is only Google and Google in two times. here is my code;

In Portfolio class;

```
    trainingArrayList = new ArrayList<Training>();

    //creates and open the database so we can use it
    DatabaseHelper db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance();

    // Getting a cursor to fetch data from the database
    final Cursor cursor = db.select("SELECT * FROM training");

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
            Training training = Training.getInstance();
            training.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRAINING_ID)));
            training.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRAINING_TITLE)));
            training.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRAINING_DESCRIPTION)));
            training.setDate(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRAINING_DATE)));
            training.setLocation(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRAINING_LOCATION)));

            this.trainingArrayList.add(training);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
```

My Training Class is :

```
public class Training {

private static Training instance = null;

// global variables
public int id;
public String title;
public String description;
public String date;
public String location;
private Trainer trainer;

private ArrayList<Trainee> traineeArrayList;

private Training(){
    //Restrict the constructor from being instantiated
}

public static Training getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new Training();
    }
    return instance;

}

// Constructor
public Training(int _id, String title, String description, String date,
        String location) {

    this.id = _id;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.date = date;
    this.location = location;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;

}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;

}

public Trainer getTrainer() {
    return trainer;
}

public Training (Context context) {

    DatabaseHelper db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance();

    traineeArrayList = new ArrayList<Trainee>();

    Cursor cursor = db.select("SELECT * FROM person p JOIN attendance a ON p.person_id = a.person_id WHERE training_id="+this.getId()+";");

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Trainee trainee = new Trainee();
        trainee.setID(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.PERSON_ID)));
        trainee.setFirstname(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.PERSON_FIRSTNAME)));
        trainee.setLastname(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.PERSON_LASTNAME)));
        //TODO

        // Pass to the arraylist
        this.traineeArrayList.add(trainee);
    }
}

/* returns the title of training in training ;ist. 
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString() {

    return title;
}
```

My Main Activity class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    portfolio = new Portfolio(this);

    trainingListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Training>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            portfolio.getTrainingArrayList());

    setListAdapter(trainingListAdapter);
```

Comment: debug  portfolio.getTrainingArrayList() in your Main Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
...
}
```

The cursor starts before the first row. On the first iteration this moves to the first result if it exists. If the cursor is empty, or the last row has already been processed, then the loop exits

Comment: I have the constructor but while creating Training training = new Training(); . The constructor Training is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 // move the cursor pointer to position zero.
        cursor.moveToFirst();

            // if there is data after the current cursor position, add it
            // to the ArrayList.
            if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
            {
                do
                {
        // get `training` data          
        trainingArrayList.add(training);
                }
                // move the cursor's pointer up one position.
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

You are assigning data to the same instance of `Training` in your `Portfolio` class.

```
Training training = Training.getInstance();
```

The above line will give you the same instance and you are adding this same reference to ArrayList every time. Since the object is static, thats why the very last iteration's data will be updated in the Training class variable, thus you are getting the google and google because google was your last iteration's data.

**Solution:**

Make new `Training` object on every iteration like this:

```
Training training = new Training();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only ever creating one instance of your Training object. Effectively you have implemented the singleton pattern. Create a new Training object every time you advance the cursor to the next record -

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {


        Training training = new Training(cursor.getInt(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRAINING_ID)),
                cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRAINING_TITLE))
                cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRAINING_DESCRIPTION))
                cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRAINING_DATE))
                cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRAINING_LOCATION))
            );
        this.trainingArrayList.add(training);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }


public class Training {

private static Training instance = null;

// global variables
public int id;
public String title;
public String description;
public String date;
public String location;
private Trainer trainer;

private ArrayList<Trainee> traineeArrayList;

public Training(int id, String title, String description, String date, String location) {
  this.id = id;
  this.title = title;
  this.description = description;
  this.date = date; 
  this.location = location;
}
```

Comment: I tried this also. In this case the private constructor of Training need to be changes only to Training(){}.

Comment: You could create a new public constructor for Training, which takes all the required parameters to initialise itself - id, title, description etc

Comment: I have it already but still the Training class does not take private Training (){} constructor